# Authenticate with LinkedIn api using javascript issues

Tags: javascript, linkedin-jsapi

Using the Linkedin Tutorial, I'm trying to login to LinkedIn using Javascript.

The issue I have: using firebug for verification I realize that the http request does not show errors, but the LinkedIn Button is not rendered and the http response is:

```
(function(){
var r=("true" === "false"), a=("false" === "false"), h=[], e=("false" === "true");
var p="${SCOPE_NAME}";
var s=("SCOPE_VALID" === "SCOPE_INVALID"), n=("SCOPE_VALID" === "SCOPE_NOT_AUTHORIZED"),
d=("SCOPE_VALID" === "SCOPE_DISABLED");

if(e){
    throw new Error("An error occurred.");
}
else if (!a) {  
  throw new Error("API Key is invalid");
}
else if (s) {
  throw new Error("Scope parameter is invalid: " + p);
}
else if (n) {
  throw new Error("Scope parameter is not authorized: " + p);
}
else if (d) {
  throw new Error("Scope parameter is disabled: " + p);
}
else if (h.length == 0) {
  throw new Error("You must specify a valid JavaScript API Domain as part of this key's
configuration.");
}
else if (!r) {
  throw new Error("JavaScript API Domain is restricted to "+h.join(", "));
}

else {
  throw new Error("Unknown Error");
}
})();
```

Can you assist me in solving this issue?

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to https://www.linkedin.com/secure/developer
2. Click on the application name you're using.
3. Add your domain name('http://www.example.com') or if you are using
   localhost then add ('http://localhost') to JavaScript API Domains:
4. Save changes.